# AI algorithm possible solution for shortest path

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, heuristics, minesweeper

I need advice for heuristic for minesweeper game. If found 10 fields without mine, i am curious how to estimate what should be the next field to open? I was thinking about finding possibility for mines around every field with number, and at the end of computation to choose a field with least possibility but i don't think it will give me good results, because i need to open already safe field and what i need is to open a field which will opens the biggest area on the board. I would like to read good ideas, but just without cheating algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

You could try an A* search with Monte Carlo simulation. That is, to define a cost/reward to each type of cell being opened (each type of action).

Assume you have K different actions you can perform (a_1,a_2,a_3...) at current timestep.

1. For each action (open cell X), and use the game model to simulate what would happen next. Store the reward for the sequence of actions, and accumulate the reward to the original action. You can add probability weight to actions and the consequences to make the estimate more accurate.
2. Take the average of simulated rewards for each action and action sequence. After M simulations at depth D (where M and D are just pre-defined values to ensure the algorithm doesn't take too long), choose one action from (a_1,a_2,a_3...) with highest simulated reward. Pruning is necessary to make this method efficient (that is, not to waste time on actions that are definitely not lead to high reward after a few steps simulations)